# Check if time.now is between two times in the day

Tags: go

I have a time object which, will be dynamically generated with the following:

```
timeNow := time.Now()
```

I need to check if the time now is within a given start and end time.

So I will have two strings like so:

```
startTime := "8:00 AM"
endTime := "10:00 PM"
```

I will then somehow cast those strings to time objects, and check with times inbuilt .before() and .after() functions.

The problem is, I'm unsure how I create a time object, using todays date (from time.now) but from a given time, i.e a string like "8:00 AM", how is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Compare `timeNow.Hour()` against 8 and 22. Do not work on strings.

Comment: Parse all string timestamps... convert to unix timestamp integer. compare it.

Answer (score 0):

AS @Volker suggests (in the comments) if you can get the hour as an integer and compare it with `timeNow.Hour()` then thats a good approach. If you have to deal with a string (e.g. from a config file) then you can do something like this ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uBlmnYU-LWT))

```
startTime := "8:00 AM"
endTime := "10:00 PM"
now := time.Now()

// Parse the start/end times
sTimeOnly, err := time.Parse("3:04 PM", startTime)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
eTimeOnly, err := time.Parse("3:04 PM", endTime)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Add current date to the times
s := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), sTimeOnly.Hour(), sTimeOnly.Minute(), sTimeOnly.Second(), sTimeOnly.Nanosecond(), now.Location())
e := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), eTimeOnly.Hour(), eTimeOnly.Minute(), eTimeOnly.Second(), eTimeOnly.Nanosecond(), now.Location())

if now.Before(s) || now.After(e) {
    fmt.Println("Outside of time range")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Within time range")
}
```

Note: time.Now() returns the current local time (i.e. the time in whatever timezone your machine is configured to use). This is important because if the machine the application is running on is not configured to run in the correct timezone then the results will not be as you expect.